# Disable Subtitles/Closed Captions on embedded YouTube video

Tags: ios, video, youtube, uiwebview

I have an iOS app that plays YouTube video by embedding it in a UIWebView. This allows it to be displayed in the native system player. I do this using this library: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

This video has a subtitle track that I would like to keep as an option, but I would like it to be disabled by default. The iOS player seems to enable these subtitles no matter what I do. I have experimented with the different embed options such as cc_load_policy, with no luck.

How can I disable subtitles by default on these videos?